# Glob files except that including some expression

Tags: c++, shell

I want to write a command to build `FooMain.cc` among the following files:

```
$ ls src
FooMain.cc
FooMain2.cc
BarMain.cc
Helper.cc
Helper.h
FileToInclude.cc
FileToInclude.h
...
```

Each main file (those including `Main`) has `main()` function and they require all the other files without `Main` in filenames.

The straightforward way to build would be like:

```
clang++ [options] FooMain.cc Helper.cc FileToInclude.cc ...
```

Here the expression `HelperOne.cc FileToInclude.cc ...` includes all the files but those including `Main`.
What I want to do is rephrase this expression with glob expression

```
clang++ [options] FooMain.cc [Some clever glob expression]
```

I looked up for a while but could not find similar questions.
Appreciate any clues. Thank you!

Comment: How about using `Helper*.cc`?

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. The helper functions include those that do not match `Helper*.cc`; The only condition is that they end with `.cc` and never include `Main`.

Comment: Maybe using regular expressions, but I'd rather pick a build system and define the "build recipes" for each project. You could start with a simple *makefile*.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ksh93`, `bash` with the *extglob* option turned on (`shopt -s extglob`), or `zsh` with the *ksh_glob* option turned on (`setopt ksh_glob`):

```sh
$ clang++ [options] FooMain.cc !(*Main*).cc
```

Using `zsh` with the *extended_glob* option turned on (`setopt extended_glob`):

```sh
$ clang++ [options] FooMain.cc *.cc~*Main*
```